# I need to create three buttons and each button shows different text

Tags: android

I need to create three buttons in Android Studio and each button shows different text. When the user clicks on first button it shows "Welcome" at the right side of the button. When the user click on the second button the "Welcome" message will disappear, and in the same place a"Hello" message will appear. Third button is the same with difference message"Bye". Here my code and thanks in advance.

XML Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.Recipes">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="R1"
    android:id="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/response"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/click_btn" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="R2"
    android:id="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_below="@+id/click_btn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="R3"
    android:id="@+id/button16"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button15"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button15" />
```

Java Code:

```
package com.example.android;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static com.example.android.R.*;


public class Recipes extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView resp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(layout.activity_recipes);
    resp = (TextView)this.findViewById(id.response);
    Button b = (Button)this.findViewById(id.click_btn);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    resp.setText("Welcome ");
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_recipes, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    resp.setText("Welcome ");
}
}
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `setOnClickListener` for all Button's in same way as currently doing for `click_btn` Button .

To change text of TextView clicked use `switch-case` inside onClick method like:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

     switch(v.getId()){

      case R.id.click_btn: /** on click_btn button click */
        resp.setText("Welcome ");
        break;

      case R.id.button15: /** on button15 button click */
       resp.setText("Hello ");
        break;

      case R.id.button16: /** on button16 button click */
       resp.setText("Bye ");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: it works thanks. I need also when the user changes the position to a landscape mode the buttons show the text and an image. How can I do that please.

Comment: @AbuMohanad: see following example for handing data in device rotation http://techblogon.com/android-screen-orientation-change-rotation-example/

Comment: so when i need the buttons do something else I have to type my codes under `public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
              if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {` is that correct?